# The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.) FACEBOOK VIDEO UPLOAD

Tags: ios, facebook

I wrote following code for uploading video to facebook from iOS device.

```
-(void)uploadVideo {

    NSLog(@"UPload Videio ");


    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mov"];

    NSLog(@"Path is %@", filePath);

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   videoData, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                                   @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                                   nil];
    //  [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
    //                         andParams:params
    //                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
    //                       andDelegate:self];

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {


        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                              completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                                  if(!error) {
                                      NSLog(@"OK: %@", result);
                                  } else
                                      NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

                              }];

    } else {

        // We don't have an active session in this app, so lets open a new
        // facebook session with the appropriate permissions!

        // Firstly, construct a permission array.
        // you can find more "permissions strings" at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/
        // In this example, we will just request a publish_stream which is required to publish status or photos.

        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"publish_stream",
                                nil];



        //[self controlStatusUsable:NO];
        // OPEN Session!
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                      FBSessionState status,
                                                      NSError *error) {
                                      // if login fails for any reason, we alert
                                      if (error) {

                                          // show error to user.

                                      } else if (FB_ISSESSIONOPENWITHSTATE(status)) {

                                          // no error, so we proceed with requesting user details of current facebook session.


                                          [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                                                       parameters:params
                                                                       HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                                                                completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                                    //  [FBRequestConnection setVideoMode:NO];

                                                                    if(!error) {
                                                                        NSLog(@"VEEERRRRRRR: %@", result);
                                                                    } else
                                                                        NSLog(@"VVEEERRRRREEEERRR: %@", error.localizedDescription);

                                                                }];





                                          //[self promptUserWithAccountNameForUploadPhoto];
                                      }
                                      // [self controlStatusUsable:YES];
                                  }];
    }
}
```

This gives me error 
***The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)***

I don't know what is wrong with facebook. It uploads image, text, but in video it gives this error.

NOTE:

1. It is not due to send again and again, as I also tested by making new account and resetting iOS Device.
2. sample.mov also exists and works with graph api, but issue is with this SDK.

Thanks.

Comment: Dude Have you found the solution?? coz I'm having same problem

Comment: Have you tried changing @"title" to @"name"? There is no field called "title" in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few causes for seeing com.facebook.sdk error 5:

- Session is is not open. Validate.
- Facebook has detected that you're spamming the system. Change video name.
- Facebook has a defined limit using the SDK. Try a different app.
- Wrong publish permission. Give publish_actions a spin.
- more here... ?

Answer (score 0):

Having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24755016/3905416) solution. I was able solve this problem.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result, NSError *error)
    {
       [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                    parameters:params
                                    HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                        if(!error)
                                                        {
                                                            NSLog(@"SUCCESS RESULT: %@", result);
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                        }

                                                    }];


    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem all day when I noticed that my app does not appear in:

Settings App->Facebook->"ALLOW THESE APPS TO USE YOUR ACCOUNT"

This made me realize that posting to Facebook is not permitted by default, you must prompt the user for their permission:

```
 [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                         defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                       completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error)
   {
     if (!error)
     {
        // UPLOAD VIDEO HERE AND THAT ERROR 5 SHOULD GO AWAY
     }
   }];
```